# MMenu Plugin for jQuery Mobile in multi-html android app

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, mmenu

I'm using `mmenu` plugin for my android/phonegap app.

I have a multi-html structure:

- index.html
- secondPage.html
- thirdPage.html
- ...
- ...

I inserted the `mmenu` into `index.html` successfully. Now, how can I add the same `mmenu` on others pages?

Comment: the same way you insert it into first page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing for a mobile app and have setup the menu as a .js file and just include this file in all pages that I want the menu to appear.  That way I only have one menu file to update and the same menu appears across all pages.